# Java Swing GUI Try/Catch Block

Tags: java, swing, try-catch

I'm just learning Java exception handling and Java in general.  I've made a Swing GUI where the user will enter integers into two fields and then click a radio button with an arithmetic function and the answer will appear in a third text field.  I want to include a try/catch block to catch exceptions if the user leaves one of the first two fields blank or enters something other than integers and a second catch if the user tries to divide by zero.  The form works functionally, however the errors aren't caught and only return the stack trace and crash the program.  I have a feeling I just have the try/catch block in the wrong place but the more I move it around the worse things get.  Could somebody point to where I went wrong?

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Main extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private JTextField aTextField;
    private JRadioButton dRadioButton;
    private ButtonGroup buttonGroup;
    private JLabel aLabel;
    private JRadioButton cRadioButton;
    private JRadioButton bRadioButton;
    private JRadioButton aRadioButton;
    private JTextField cTextField;
    private JTextField bTextField;

    /**
     * Auto-generated main method to display this JFrame
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Main inst = new Main();
                inst.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                inst.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public Main() {
        super();
        initGUI();
    }

    private void initGUI() {
        try {
            setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            getContentPane().setLayout(null);
            {
                aTextField = new JTextField();
                getContentPane().add(aTextField);
                aTextField.setBounds(12, 49, 62, 30);
            }
            {
                bTextField = new JTextField();
                getContentPane().add(bTextField);
                bTextField.setBounds(178, 49, 62, 31);
            }
            {
                cTextField = new JTextField();
                getContentPane().add(cTextField);
                cTextField.setBounds(297, 49, 62, 30);
            }
            {
                aRadioButton = new JRadioButton();
                getContentPane().add(aRadioButton);
                aRadioButton.setText("+");
                aRadioButton.setBounds(91, 18, 43, 20);
                aRadioButton.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe UI", 1, 16));
                aRadioButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                        aRadioButtonActionPerformed(evt);
                    }
                });
                getButtonGroup().add(aRadioButton);
            }
            {
                bRadioButton = new JRadioButton();
                getContentPane().add(bRadioButton);
                bRadioButton.setText("-");
                bRadioButton.setBounds(91, 53, 43, 20);
                bRadioButton.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe UI", 1, 16));
                bRadioButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                        bRadioButtonActionPerformed(evt);
                    }
                });
                getButtonGroup().add(bRadioButton);
            }
            {
                cRadioButton = new JRadioButton();
                getContentPane().add(cRadioButton);
                cRadioButton.setText("*");
                cRadioButton.setBounds(91, 99, 43, 20);
                cRadioButton.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe UI", 1, 16));
                cRadioButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                        cRadioButtonActionPerformed(evt);
                    }
                });
                getButtonGroup().add(cRadioButton);
            }
            {
                dRadioButton = new JRadioButton();
                getContentPane().add(dRadioButton);
                getContentPane().add(getALabel());
                dRadioButton.setText("/");
                dRadioButton.setBounds(91, 140, 46, 20);
                dRadioButton.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe UI", 1, 16));
                dRadioButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                        dRadioButtonActionPerformed(evt);
                    }
                });
                getButtonGroup().add(dRadioButton);
            }
            pack();
            setSize(400, 300);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "Error: You must enter an integer");

        } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "Error: You cannot divide by zero");
        }
    }

    private ButtonGroup getButtonGroup() {
        if (buttonGroup == null) {
            buttonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
        }
        return buttonGroup;
    }

    private JLabel getALabel() {
        if (aLabel == null) {
            aLabel = new JLabel();
            aLabel.setText("=");
            aLabel.setBounds(249, 56, 30, 16);
            aLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe UI", 1, 16));
        }
        return aLabel;
    }

    private void aRadioButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        String a = aTextField.getText();
        int i = Integer.parseInt(a);
        String b = bTextField.getText();
        int j = Integer.parseInt(b);
        int k = i + j;
        cTextField.setText(Integer.toString(k));
    }

    private void bRadioButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        String a = aTextField.getText();
        int i = Integer.parseInt(a);
        String b = bTextField.getText();
        int j = Integer.parseInt(b);
        int k = i - j;
        cTextField.setText(Integer.toString(k));
    }

    private void cRadioButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        String a = aTextField.getText();
        int i = Integer.parseInt(a);
        String b = bTextField.getText();
        int j = Integer.parseInt(b);
        int k = i * j;
        cTextField.setText(Integer.toString(k));
    }

    private void dRadioButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        String a = aTextField.getText();
        int i = Integer.parseInt(a);
        String b = bTextField.getText();
        int j = Integer.parseInt(b);
        int k = i / j;
        cTextField.setText(Integer.toString(k));
    }

    }


Here is the stack trace I receive:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "vvvv"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at Main.aRadioButtonActionPerformed(Main.java:154)
at Main.access$0(Main.java:152)
at Main$2.actionPerformed(Main.java:78)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JToggleButton$ToggleButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: The exceptions will be raised only within the context of the radio button action listeners, try wrapping the contents of these methods in try-catch statements

Comment: Swing is an event driven environment, this means that things happen in a non linear fashion. By the time your action listeners are triggered, the code in your initUI method has already executed and the method has exited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move your try-catch to the action preformed methods, right now, they are only in when Java is setting up the GUI, when the user preforms the action (actionPreformed) those methods will be called, therefore they need the try-catch, not the setup method.

```
private void cRadioButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    try {

          String a = aTextField.getText();
          int i = Integer.parseInt(a);
          String b = bTextField.getText();
          int j = Integer.parseInt(b);
          int k = i * j;
          cTextField.setText(Integer.toString(k));

       } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "Error: You must enter an integer");

       } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "Error: You cannot divide by zero");
    }
}
```

Add the try-catch to all the ActionPreformed methods that use this similar code, just make sure each actionPreformed method still has it's own code, just with the try-catch block around it

Comment: Excellent, that solved my problem and helped me understand why it wasn't working before.  I knew I had it in the wrong place I just couldn't figure out where to put it.  Thank you!!

Comment: @user2948381- but if user will select radio button, it'll prompt error, whether user didn't input in any of field.
See my different answer

Answer (score 2):

You should put the try catch block where your `Integer.parseInt()` calls.

Answer (score 1):

You'll get exception if you won't check your every event method, so you can do something like that to solve it,

```
private void aRadioButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    String a = aTextField.getText();
    String b = bTextField.getText();



    // you may get empty string here so check if the texbox is empty ?
 int i=0,j=0;

        try{

    if(a.length()>0 || b.length()>0){
         i = Integer.parseInt(a);
         j = Integer.parseInt(b);
    }else{
        if(a.length()<1 && b.length()>0){

            i = Integer.parseInt(a);
        }else{
            if(b.length()<1 && a.length()>0)
            j = Integer.parseInt(b);
        }
    }


    int k = i + j;
        }catch(Exception e){
          System.out.println("Exception:"+e);
          }
    cTextField.setText(Integer.toString(k));
}
```

do the same thing for you -,*,/ radio button listeners too